# BSOD while updating to Windows 11

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-11

I have been trying to updating my Windows 10 computer to Windows 11 for about a month now (maybe longer), and every time I do it I get the Windows Blue Screen upon startup of Windows 11.

When I restart the computer from the options that come up after blue screen, Windows 10 starts up (I am assuming it rolls back the changes due to a startup/install failure).

What steps can I take to fix this issue so that I can get Windows 11 installed on this computer?

- Upgrade is performed through Windows Update.
- SetupDiag results:

```
SetupDiag was unable to match to any known failure signatures.
SetupDiag version: 1.6.2107.27002
System Information:
    Machine Name = DESKTOP-S1PJCP7
    Manufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Model = B450 AORUS PRO WIFI
    HostOSArchitecture = 1033
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 
    BiosVendor = F62d
    BiosVersion = F62d
    HostOSVersion = 
    HostOSBuildString = 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.22000.434 (co_release_svc_prod1.220104-1741)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Core
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 1/23/2022 2:10:04 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 1/23/2022 3:27:47 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 01:17:43
    CV = 9FDplKUJwUy/emAa
    ReportId = B36D5C9B-136D-4D55-902E-BE3E002B8FA0
```

When I upgrade I get the following error:

> Upgrade to Windows 11
> Failed to install on ‎3/‎6/‎2022 - 0xc1900101

When looking up the error I see that it relates to [drivers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-help-with-windows-upgrade-and-installation-errors-ea144c24-513d-a60e-40df-31ff78b3158a), so I updated all my AMD, Intel, and Nvidia drivers manually and did a windows update for any others. I can't figure out what would be causing this still.

Comment: The only computer I know that updates BIOS by Windows Update is the Microsoft Surface computer.  Try updating BIOS in Windows 10 before updating to Windows 11.

Comment: I had to do I BIOS update before I updated, as the BIOS didn't have 1 of the two required settings to run Windows 11. It now has support for it, however, I still get the BSOD.

Comment: Run PC Health in Microsoft Update settings to see if you still need something to update to Windows 11

Comment: @Ramhound No, I could not find `Intel® Smart Sound Technology (Intel® SST) Audio Controller` within the Device manager. I ran `Driver Updater` through `CCleaner` about 1 hour after I posted this question and there were 17 outdated drivers that I had the software update to the latest versions, so that could fix the issue...

Comment: Yeah, the last time Windows would let me update to windows 11 was about 5 days ago. I then just today installed the drivers through CCleaner.

Comment: To get the BSOD error, I will just have to wait until Windows update allows me to install again to get that information, unless there is another way to know?

Comment: Run the `Windows 11 Installation Assistant` instead of waiting an unknown amount of time

Comment: Please provide us with the output to Setup Diag.  You have not provided us with enough information to answer your question.  0xc1900101 is also caused by system corruption.  You should also run the appropriate DISM and SFC commands to verify the integrity of your system files